# More text in navbar - Flexdashboard Rmd

Tags: r, r-markdown, navbar, flexdashboard

Did anyone experienced this problem?

I would like to add more text (dynamically, to the right side of navbar) in Rmd flexdashboard

My current navbar looks like this:
[image]

code:

```
title: "Influencer Adex Report"
date: "`r analysis_date`"
Author: 'Peter Fico'
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
```

I Would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to add new text element to the right side of navbar in Rmd?
Thanks for any advice in advance

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to add this to the code:

````
---
title: "Influencer Adex Report"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    navbar:
        - { title: "New Desired Text!", align: right}
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Dashboard 
=====================================


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

```
    
Data 
=====================================
   
Raw Data 
=====================================
````

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Right, is there an option to make that text dynamic? Meaning that to show value assigned in variable (in title that is not a problem, here, due to {} is.) Thanks again